# Getting a parameter from class object with no '__getitem__' attribute?

Tags: python, class, proj

I am using `pyproj.Geod` to calculate geographic distances, and I would like to use the diameter of the earth defined by the object for another calculation.

When there is no `__getitem__` attribute and the object is not indexable, is there a way of extracting a value from it?

Calling the object:

```
import pyproj
g = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84') # Use WGS84 ellipsoid
```

Trying to call it by parameter name:

```
print g['a'] # the diameter parameter
TypeError: 'Geod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Testing indexing:

```
print g[0] 
TypeError: 'Geod' object does not support indexing
```

**Update:** Calling `print dir(g)`:

```
print dir(g)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_fwd', '_inv', '_npts', 'a', 'b', 'es', 'f', 'fwd', 'initstring', 'inv', 'npts', 'sphere']
```

Comment: Why would it need to have a `__getitem__` on it? do a `print dir(obj)` to see what attributes are available on it.

Comment: What is the 'object' ???

Comment: @danodonovan: presumably an instance of [`pyproj.Geod`](http://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/pyproj.Geod-class.html)..

Comment: This project is backed by a C library, it may well be that the data you are looking for is not exposed at all.

Comment: Thank you Martijn. Good way to learn about `__getitem__` and class attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function?

Comment: That was it! Using `dir(g)` to verify the name of the attribute first, I then did `print getattr(g,'a')`, which gave me what I was looking for. Thanks Martijn and Michael!

Comment: But then, that would be equivalent to `print g.a`. You only need `getattr` in cases, where you have the name of the property as a string and you need to dynamically retrieve it. If you know already that it's called `a`, just use the dot notation.